# DistributionPublicUrl String length limit

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdistribution

Can anyone know what is the DistributionPublicUrl in ContentDistribution object  String length limit in Salesforce ? I was trying to create an DistributionPublic URL whenever a new file  is created or uploaded  in Salesforce for external able to view the file and store the URL

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. An interesting question, but you didn't demonstrate any research. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for some guidance then [edit] your question to provide what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time I've posted a question. Thanks for your guidance i will edit my question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tooling API and the following query revealed that the length is 256:

```
SELECT
        DataType,
        Description,
        DeveloperName,
        DurableId,
        EntityDefinitionId,
        ExtraTypeInfo,
        Id,
        Label,
        Length,
        MasterLabel,
        NamespacePrefix,
        Precision,
        QualifiedApiName,
        Scale,
        ValueTypeId
        FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'ContentDistribution' AND QualifiedApiName = 'DistributionPublicUrl'
```

The output for me was:

| Id | DataType | DeveloperName | DurableId | EntityDefinitionId | Label | Length | MasterLabel | Precision | QualifiedApiName | Scale | ValueTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000000000000AAA | Text(256) | DistributionPublicUrl | ContentDistribution.DistributionPublicUrl | ContentDistribution | External Link | **256** | External Link | 0 | DistributionPublicUrl | 0 | string |